# git stash newly created files

Tags: git

I have a master branch in git, for the recent enhancement I wrote above 20 new java files.

then I realize that I am in master branch and I am not suppose to commit changes in master branch directly.

So I created new branch angular-changes.

When I tried to switch to new branch all newly added and existing modified files were in my upstaged area, so eclipse promoted whether to stash or reset changes. I choose stash and gave a name to that stash.

After switching to new branch i.e. angular-changes. when I tried applying stashed changes, it did not add newly added files. that files which I modified in master branch only got merged.

Is there anyway to recover those files?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line : you want to run `git stash apply --index` on top of the clean head of your branch.

First you need to check that the first stash is still what you had on master :

```
git stash list --oneline  # this will print a hash and the stash message
                          # for each stash
```

You can check that the first message is the one you expect, and that the content of the stash contains all that you had (inspect the content of `<hash>`, and its parents)